# jQuery News Ticker - Smooth Start

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

EDIT :  to make the objective clear, ultimately the ticker should fadeIn cleanly when the document is ready and the first animation has begun, there is a minor update to the code and a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/pushplaybang/aFSJk/  although the start is still a little choppy its an improvement

I'm currently building a ticker for testimonials, which works quite well overall except that I'm attempting to use `setTimout` to fade the ticker in once the page has loaded, while using `setTimout` stops the first item for being shown while the page is loading, but rather than fading in gently as I intended, it snaps into place rather abruptly.

Can some one correct the way I'm doing this?  Is there a better way to have it fade in?

Note that the below would be wrapped in a document ready function, and in the accompanying CSS the container is initially set to `display:none`.

```
function bangingTicker(container,element) {
    
    var tickContainer = $(container);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
    tickContainer.fadeIn(1000);
    },6200);
    
        function tick(){
            var tickElem = tickContainer.children(element);
            tickElem.eq(1).siblings().animate({
                opacity: 0
                },400, function() {
                    tickContainer.stop(true,true).delay(10).animate({
                    'margin-top': 120
                    },0,function() {
                        tickContainer.delay(100).animate({
                        'margin-top': 20
                        },8000);
                    });
                        tickElem.first().appendTo(tickContainer);
                        tickElem.eq(1).delay(200).animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        },400);
                    });
         
        }
        
        setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 6000);
    
}

bangingTicker('#testi_ticker','li');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after working on this for a while today I've gotten it to work in the way that I want, though I still feel like the code could be improved - I want as little reliance on the css / html as possible  but it works and looks great as well.

Check out this js fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/pushplaybang/aFSJk/3/

the summary is :

- drop the setTimout all together
- run the tick function once simultaeously to setting the setInterval function
- this stops the delay before the animation starts.
- wrap the entire tick function in the callback to the fadeIn
- set opacity to 0 in the css for the child elements so they are only faded in by the tick function

Comment: note that while the above works quite well, JSLInt in jsfiddle is returning an error Error:
Problem at line 37 character 31: Missing semicolon.
setInterval(function(){ tick() }, 4000);

Implied global: $ 1,11

Comment: put an semicolon after tick() function and everything will be ok :) tick();

Comment: awesome, that sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RzMTj/1/). Is this what you need?

Comment: Not Quite, I'll edit the question to maybe make the objective more clear, while this seems to have the fadeIn working, I want the fade in to happen just after the first setInterval function runs so that the ticker fades in with the animation running, as opposed to currently where the UL appears and then the banging ticker function starts to run.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle link. I've made some changes so maybe is this what yo want :)

Comment: hey I've just done an update myself as well [link]http://jsfiddle.net/pushplaybang/aFSJk/  its slightly better but I think the issue is coming in at the setInterval - this link is slightly smoother than yours

Comment: check my answer below, thanks for your input, if you think the script can be more elegant, I'd lvoe the input